# API call issue - PHP /JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

If you check the below ajax header picture, I am able to pass the object in stringify format. Below code is of my api, which receives this header values.
 I am getting `Internal Server Error 500` .Please help.
[image]

```
let param ={
      state_code:'11',
      products:JSON.stringify(productList),
      order_type:1
    }
    this.myserive.getCharges(param, () => {});
```

in API PHP

```
$products = isset($this->param['products']) ? json_decode($this->param['products'],true) : [];
foreach($products as $p_id => $product){
                $productWeight = 125;
                $weight = (floatval($productWeight) * intval($product['quantity'])) / 1000;
                $totalWeight += $weight;
                $totalPrice += $product['price'];
            }
```

Note : To check productList value you can check the image link.

To debug, I sent object without stringifying the object. and returned the $param in PHP API. I receive all params as it is from PHP API, except the prducts , it returns [object OBject] (string version of object.) (**This means API call is proper**) Thats why I did JSON.stringy for products before sending as param and then in php I am doing json_decode. But its giving 500 server error.

Comment: show us the full error message found inside 'Network' tab of your inspector and click on the request causing the error

Comment: @henokg error message is `{status: "ERROR", message: "Token already exists"}` > Makes any sense?

Comment: thats it? i mean it doesn't give you any clue on the error line? mostly internal server errors are shown with their corresponding error line?

Comment: yeah that's it .. :|

Comment: do you have any type of middleware on your backend?

Comment: are `$totalWeight` and `$totalPrice` initialised before the loop?

Comment: Where is your token initalization? It looks like your calling it twice

Comment: @RamRaider yes.

Comment: without seeing more of the php code then it is hard to know what is causing this here. As you are using `$this` it is presumably within a class?

Comment: @RamRaider Yes the API is in codeignitor

Comment: @RamRaider - The way I am sending the `JSON.strigify(productList)` and then in php  I am doing `json_decode($this->param['products'],true)` , Is that all correct ? Or is there any other alternative which I can check to pass multidimensional object to PHP and use in loop